# Link EF 6 entity to existing read only view in sql server

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

In my mvc 5 ef6 application I need to manage two different dbcontext: the first points to my own db whit all the data related to this app.
the second db context is used to get data from an existing database, namely two views, one for staff data and one for partner data.

So I have an externalDbContext

```
public class ExternalDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ExternalDbContext() : base("ExternalDbContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Partner> Partners { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Staff> Staffers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Partner>().ToTable("MY_PARTNER_TABLE");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Staff>().ToTable("MY_STAFF_TABLE");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Partner>().HasKey(t => t.CustomKey);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Staff>().HasKey(t => t.EmployeeId);
    }
```

}

```
}
```

Using server explorer I can access data in views, but when in my app I try to get data from the views

```
       var objCtx = new ExternalDbContext();
       var utente = (from u in objCtx.Staffers
                      where u.UserID1 == myuser
                      select u);
```

I get an error message

```
 Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database 
 does not contain model metadata. 
 Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created 
 using Code First or Code First Migrations.
```

I suppose this has to do with the fact that these views have not been created by code first migrations. Fact is that I cannot create these views, they already exist, i'm not the dba and I can (and must) only read them.

Any suggestion?

Comment: have you only view in the context ?

Answer (score 1):

Kill off the database compatibility check by setting your database initialiser to null in your context constructor.

Common practice is to put it in the static constructor:

```
static ExternalDbContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<ExternalDbContext>(null);
}
```

But it can alternatively go in the default public constructor

```
public ExternalDbContext() : base("ExternalDbContext")
{
   Database.SetInitializer<ExternalDbContext>(null);
}
```

Comment: Changed public ExternalDbContext() : base("ExternalDbContext") to static ExternalDbContext(), added the suggested statement, but same error is fired

Comment: You'll need the static constructor in addition to the public default constructor - the first controls database initialisation and the second controls the connection string.

Comment: Please forgive me, but where should I put the static constructor?

Comment: Its fine to just put it in the default constructor instead - see updated answer